# Class Helper in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I was wondering if we could use Helpers as class in Rails.
The interpreter requires helper to be a Module, but I want it as a class.

I have two solutions :

```
module ModHelper
    class C
    #stuff
    end
end
```

Which impose me to write ModHelper::C.my_method instead of ModHelper.my_method ...

Or :

```
module ModHelper
#nothing
end

class C
#stuff
end
```

Which is a bit dirty.

Is someone have a better solution ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Just use my Helper as a Class.

Comment: Then what you need is not likely to be a helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that you can just do `ShortName = MyModule::UselessName`.

Comment: It sound good ! I can write `module Mod class C end end C = Mod::C` Not perfectly proper, but very nice, thanks.